Framer Motion hover delay inherit from another animation
The problem is the delay applied in animate variants is applied in the hover as well.
I tried to add transition with delay: 0 in whilehover but don't work.
{/* More Code */}
<motion.div
  key="agua"
  initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
  animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
  whileHover={{
    scale: 1.1,
    transition: { type: 'spring', duration: 0.5, delay: 0 },
  }}
  variants={{
    initial: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
    animate: { opacity: 1, scale: 1, transition: { delay: 0.7 } },
  }}
  transition={{ type: 'spring', delay: 0 }}
  className="order-7 flex justify-center sm:col-span-2 sm:row-span-3"
>
  {/* Div Content*/}
</motion.div>
{/* More Code */}

RIght Now
I want this, with initial delay for apparition
